# MongoServerError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, acid

In the below code, I'm trying to update multiple collections in one transaction:

```
  # update.js
  import Task from "../models/Task.js";
    import UserScreening from "../models/UserScreening.js";

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
      ['_id1','_id2','_id3'].forEach(async (r) => {
          await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(
            r,
            { $push: { UserScreening: userscreening, user: existingUser } },
            { session }
          );
        });
   userscreening = await UserScreening.update({},{}{ session });
    session.commitTransaction();
```

So I'm using a transaction because I need all operations to either succeed or fail.

I don't know the proper approach for array of `_ids`. I'm facing errors in interating. The error reads:

> MongoServerError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteConflict` errors are part of the concurrency management game.

Imagine two parallel transactions trying to update the same document in a collection at almost the same time.

To guarantee [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation), any ACID-compliant database has to implement such guardrails in place and hand over the decision back to the client.

In MongoDB, the transactions have two kinds of APIs: [Core and Callback](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-in-applications/). The callback API's `withTransaction` automatically retries [transient errors](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-in-applications/#std-label-transient-transaction-error) including `WriteConflict`, however, the core API, obviously does not come with such fancy whistles and it's all up to the implementor.

It's worth noting that `WriteConflict` might still happen if one utilizes the Callback API. That is, usually, when even an internal retry fails due to timing of the transaction commits.

Overall, the first course of action would be to retry the failing transaction.